# MS Sql Login failed for user

Tags: java, sql-server, hikaricp

I have java app with Hikari connection pool to MSSql databse.
It works perfect when i use my database, but when i want to connect to remote database i get error: Login failed for user. I saw some problems about this here but did not found the solution. I tried to change the port on MSSQL and etc but did not succeeded.

Error message:

```
    Caused by: com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool$PoolInitializationException: Failed to initialize pool: Login failed for user 'user'. ClientConnectionId:a45173d9-e047-49a1-b8d0-e8507ad2a7b9
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.throwPoolInitializationException(HikariPool.java:544)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:536)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.<init>(HikariPool.java:112)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource.<init>(HikariDataSource.java:72)
    at com.mypackage.DAOConnPool.<clinit>(DAOConnPool.java:33)
    ... 2 more
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Login failed for user 'user'. ClientConnectionId:a45173d9-e047-49a1-b8d0-e8507ad2a7b9
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException.makeFromDatabaseError(SQLServerException.java:258)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onEOF(tdsparser.java:256)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:108)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:4290)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:3157)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:82)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:3121)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7151)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:2478)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:2026)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:1687)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:1528)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:866)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnectionInternal(SQLServerDataSource.java:968)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource.getConnection(SQLServerDataSource.java:78)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newConnection(PoolBase.java:356)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase.newPoolEntry(PoolBase.java:199)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.createPoolEntry(HikariPool.java:444)
    at com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariPool.checkFailFast(HikariPool.java:515)
    ... 5 more
```

Here is my config:

```
mssql.connectionstring= jdbc:sqlserver://IP:1433;databaseName=object_registry;integratedSecurity=true;
mssql.jdbcdriver =com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource 
mssql.user = user
mssql.pass = password
mssql.minConnectionPerPartition = 5
mssql.maxConnectionPerPartition = 10
mssql.partitionCount=1
```

Here is my connection:

```
 try (Connection conn = DAOConnPool.getConnection(); Statement statement = conn.createStatement();) {
      statement.executeUpdate(db_statement);
```

Here is DAOConnPool class:

```
  public class DAOConnPool {

  private static HikariConfig config = new HikariConfig();
  private static HikariDataSource dataSource;

 static {      

  config.setDataSourceClassName(ConfigurationFile.getProperty("mssql.jdbcdriver"));
  config.setJdbcUrl(ConfigurationFile.getProperty("mssql.connectionstring"));     
  config.setUsername(ConfigurationFile.getProperty("mssql.user"));
  config.setPassword(ConfigurationFile.getProperty("mssql.pass"));
  //config.addDataSourceProperty("cachePrepStmts", "true");
  //config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSize", "250");
  //config.addDataSourceProperty("prepStmtCacheSqlLimit", "2048");
  dataSource = new HikariDataSource(config);
}

}

public DAOConnPool() {
}

public static Connection getConnection() throws SQLException {
  return dataSource.getConnection();
}

}
```

Comment: Please add the complete error message.

Comment: The question is edited, Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to remove :

```
 config.setDataSourceClassName(ConfigurationFile.getProperty("mssql.jdbcdriver"));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are trying to connect to the database remotely using windows authentication. In connection string this

```
integratedSecurity=true
```

define that you are connecting via windows authentication. If you want to connect via network you should give the appropriate privilege. If you are connecting server authentication, you need to remove that attribute from your connecting string.

Comment: I tried without that and i also get the error. I am trying to make Sql Server Authentication